# What are the letters on the right side of auto-complete's popup?

Tags: emacs

For example, what do the "a" and "d" mean in this screenshot?

[image: screenshot of Emacs's auto-complete package in action]

(A bit of background detail: I'm using Emacs 24.3 on OS X 10.8.3, and the automatic completion library in question is [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/))

Answer (score 12):

[image: an image of a table in auto-complete's documentation, mapping each symbol to its meaning]

The letters are mnemonics, indicating why `auto-complete` considers a particular candidate worthy of your consideration. In the screenshot, many candidates have "d" next to them because they come from [the project's `dict` file for Python-mode](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/dict/python-mode). The "a" is for [abbrev](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html)… but I can't say much more than that because I haven't used the `abbrev` stuff yet.

Anyway, you can learn more by exploring `ac-define-source`, both its [documentation](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html#ac-define-source) and its [usages](https://github.com/search?l=&q=ac-define-source+repo%3Aauto-complete%2Fauto-complete&ref=advsearch&type=Code).